# Which would work for a multi-user Ruby setup? RVM or RBenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

At work we have a development machine setup much like a production machine. For each project running we use a different user. Until now we only did Java and PHP projects, but now I want to start doing Ruby on Rails projects, so I want to be able to setup my Rails apps the same as we do for Java and PHP, where each project has another user.

Which Ruby version manager should I use to do this? RVM or RBenv? I couldn't find anything about RBenv supporting multiple users.

When we do a multi-user (System-wide) setup of RVM is it possible to set a default Ruby version per user so there is one default RVM for everyone but overwrite this default for certain users?

Our web server is Apache so far, so is mod passenger the best choice to run my Rails projects?

I also looked at Pow, but I don't think it's a good solution to use in a multi-user setup.

Any idea's about this?

Comment: rbenv and rvm are built for single user use. I would recommend against using them system wide, they're just not built for that. It's why RVM removed it's system-wide install and documentation initially. rbenv is much more lightweight and would be easier to debug if you *did* use it in a system wide environment, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm, RVM is *definitely* built for multiple users AS WELL AS per user installations. Please see the [installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) for more information.

Also, please see the integration section and Passenger page in that section for using multiple gemsets with Passenger, however, Passenger is limited to a single Ruby.

For the ability to use any Ruby and any gemset within that Ruby's space, you want to set up Unicorn for that. You can easily use Apache and Unicorn or NGinx and Unicorn to accomplish all you want.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with the "built for multiple user". e.g. a user of the rvm group can delete a gemset created by another user of the rvm group.

Comment: exactly. its part of the rvm group which is designed for multi-user tenency. This is standard Unix permission sets. This is normal. This is how Unix groups work. There is no spciality in that regard. The same things you can do in a normal user group under unix, are the same things you can do with rvm. Using RVM doesn't magically change that. Redefine under Unix how groups work and you might be able to change that. Until then, ANY software you install for a unix group will operate like this.

Comment: I agree with you. However, the point is that rvm design, as it is _now_, allows a user to step on another's user's feet. As such, I wouldn't deploy it for my users base.

Comment: Vassilis you might want to look at the current rendition of RVM. We've implemented the ability for users to have the rvm install in /usr/local/rvm and have their gem sets and rubies in $HOME/.rvm. Yes, I admit that means that you use more disc space, however, I believe this should give you the degree of separation you're looking for.

Comment: exactly what we need, Daryl congrats!

Answer (score 2):

RVM and RBENV keep their files (rubies/gems etc) in user folders (~/.rvm, ~/.rbenv). So you can use the one you like.

You can use passenger with a small projects, but for a big ones - try Unicorn or Thin.

Comment: you can use Passenger with small projects as well. However Unicorn would probably be the better choice due to how lightweight it is, as well as that passenger is generally limited to a single ruby version.

Comment: multi-user RVM installations are not installed in ~/.rvm but in /usr/local/rvm

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme). chruby was specifically designed to allow using Rubies installed into `/usr/local/$ruby` or `/opt/$ruby`, but still allow users to install gems into `~/.gem/$ruby/$version/`. If you use chruby as root, gems are installed into `/path/to/$ruby/$gem_dir/`.